# Lefschetz operator identity, local proof

Tags: differential-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $M$ denote a Kähler manifold with Kähler form $\omega$. Let $L$ denote the Lefschetz operator acting on on $A^k(M,\mathbb{C}) \to A^{k+2}(M,\mathbb{C})$ such that $L(\eta)=\omega \wedge \eta$.

Now let $\Lambda = L^{*}$, that is $\Lambda$ defines the adjoint of the Lefschetz operator.

I am looking at the proof that $[\Lambda , \overline{\partial}]=- i \partial^{*}$, which is given by Proposition 6.5 in 'Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry' by Claire Voisin. It uses the fact that locally $\omega$ is equal to the standard Kähler form on $\mathbb{C}^n$ up to order two in $z$, and that $\Lambda$ and $\overline{\partial}$ are zero and first order differential operators respectively. It then says that it suffices to prove the proposition for the standard Kähler form on $\mathbb{C}^n$ as .

I don't understand this, can somebody explan this logic. The second order terms don't disappear after applying a first order differential onto them, so I don't understand why we can neglect them in the proof?

Comment: For every $p\in M$ you can find a neighborhood and coordinates where $\omega$ is flat up to second order terms. If you test the action of the operators in a form $\eta$, your second order terms don't disappear and became first order terms, so you haven't proved the identity in that neighborhood; however, just at $p$ all the first order terms vanish and the identity holds. Since $p$ is arbitrary, the identity holds in $M$. See also, Griffiths and Harris, Principles of Algebraic Geometry, p. 114-115.

Comment: Ah okay so it was a pointwise statement. So we are identifying the point $p$ with 0 in the coordinate chart and thus the statement clearly holds for $p$ as all terms of order $z \geq 1$ will be trivial at $p$. Given $p$ was arbitrary about any point we can find such a chart and this statement is locally true, and thus is true for all of $M$. Okay I think I get it

Comment: Feel free to write that comment into a post and I will mark it as solved.